# My angular expressions are not being rendered by the browser

Tags: html, angularjs, expression

I am learning angular js from code school and this is their code. It wont display my products rather it shows the code exactly as in {{..}}. I have thoroughly checked for errors nothing seems to work. I have tried removing th alias of *StoreController as store* and used just *StoreController*, that doesn't work either. I enclosed my entire js code in a function but that didnt work too. I have attached the picture of my result too.

**My Javascript Code in ang.js file**

```
    var app = angular.module('GemsStore',[]);

    app.controller('StoreController',function(){
        this.products=gems;
    });


    var gems=[
        {
            name:'Diamond',
            price:100,
            description:'Shiny',
            canPurchase:true,
            soldOut:false
        },

        {
            name:'Sapphire',
            price:200,
            description:'Shiny',
            canPurchase:true,
            soldOut:false
        }
    ];
```

**My html Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="GemsStore">
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>

<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<body ng-controller="StoreController as store">

<div ng-repeat="product in store.products">
    <div ng-hide="store.product.soldOut">
        <h1>{{store.product.name}}</h1>
        <h2>{{store.product.price}}</h2>
        <p>{{store.product.description}}</p>
        <button class="btn-default" ng-show="store.product.canPurchase">Add To Cart</button>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="js/ang.js"></script>o
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

[My result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOYAI.png)

[edited code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iS9XN.png)

Comment: you should include your js after angular js

Comment: Try loading angular before your `ang.js` file

Comment: did it. Doesn't work

Comment: now nothing shows up

Comment: Try removing as store from    <body ng-controller="StoreController as store">

Comment: move `var gems =[]` to inside your controller as the first line

Comment: tried them all^ no result

Comment: inside body, before your ng-repeat add this line to check if angular is initialised or not
`<p> 2+3 = {{2+3}} </p>`
also update your question to show what you have done

Comment: @CodingNinja i can't update code that doesnt work there is no point in it and i tried this expression, i get 5 the angular is initialezed

Comment: if you are getting 5, that means angular is working fine. check your code properly and the console to see any errors and rectify them

Comment: @CodingNinja i have tried them all also, i saw 2 3 or more questions in stackoverflow having the same problem and none of them was solved so i don't know what is wrong with this

Comment: update your code, then only I can understand what is wrong

Comment: @CodingNinja check the image i added by the name of edited code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JS code

```
app.controller('StoreController', function() {    
  var gems = [{
      name: 'Diamond',
      price: 100,
      description: 'Shiny',
      canPurchase: true,
      soldOut: false
    },    
    {
      name: 'Sapphire',
      price: 200,
      description: 'Shiny',
      canPurchase: true,
      soldOut: false
    }
  ];    
  this.products = gems;
});
```

Your HTML code

```
<body ng-controller="StoreController as store">
<div ng-repeat="product in store.products">
    <div ng-hide="product.soldOut">
        <h1>{{product.name}}</h1>
        <h2>{{product.price}}</h2>
        <p>{{product.description}}</p>
        <button class="btn-default" ng-show="product.canPurchase">Add To Cart</button>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/ang.js"></script>
</body>
```